# How to set the style of polygons in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

With **OpenLayers 4** I copy one or more polygons from one layer to another, and since they do not have styles, I would like to assign them one.

I can put a style on the layer but polygons do not have export styles. That's why I try to put a style to the polygons without success.

The following code returns "TypeError: ... is not a function":

```
    var Polygon= new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',//'#ffffff'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 4
          })
        });
        getDrawingLayer().getSource().addFeatures(select.getFeatures().getArray());//pass the polygons
         //getDrawingLayer().setStyle(Polygon)};//succes
getDrawingLayer().getSource().getFeatures().setStyle(Polygon);//try to set the style of polygons
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I understand, because the layer is an array, I have to assign each feature from it
with

```
getDrawingLayer (). getSource (). forEachFeature (function (feature) {
feature.setStyle (Polygon);});
```